# Cómo agregar otra opción a este switch?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

quiero saber cómo puedo agregar otra opción a mi switch, ya que tengo a la clase huésped y empleado, de empleado ya lo solucioné al hacer que el huésped pueda ingresar los datos y guarde un registro, ahora del empleado quiero ingresar datos también pero por algún motivo no me permite, recién estoy entendiendo estos conceptos por lo que solicito ayuda, mas no solucion completa a mi ejercicio para poder entender más que todo, muchas gracias de ante mano.

```
 package Main;
        import BaseDatosHospedaje.accesoDatos;
        import Datos.Empleado;
        import Datos.Huesped;
        import Datos.Habitacion;
        import Datos.FichaHospedaje;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class Presentación {
            static BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         
            //Variables
            static int n;
            static long nro;
            static FichaHospedaje oF;
            static Habitacion oH;
            static Empleado oEmp;
            static Huesped oHspd;
            static accesoDatos empleados= new accesoDatos();
            static accesoDatos huespedes=new accesoDatos();
            static accesoDatos fichas=new accesoDatos();
            static accesoDatos habitaciones=new accesoDatos();
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                int opc;
                do{
                    opc=menu();
                    switch(opc){
                        case 1: n=leerN();
                               ingresar();
                               break;
                        case 2: n=leerN();
                               ingresar();
                               break;  
                        case 3: listar();
                               break;   
                    }
                }while(opc!=4);
            }
            static int menu() throws IOException{
            int opc;
            do{
               System.out.println("HOSPEDAJE LOS CASERITOS"); 
               System.out.println("---MENÚ DE OPCIONES---");
               System.out.println("1. Registrar Empleado");
               System.out.println("2. Registrar Huesped");
               System.out.println("3. Consultar Huesped");
               System.out.println("4. SALIR");
               System.out.println("Ingrese la opción: ");
               opc=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }while(opc<1 || opc>3);
            return opc;
            }
            static int leerN()throws IOException{
                int n;
                do{  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese número de huéspedes a registrar: ");
                    n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                }while(n<=0||n>=50);
                return n;
            }
            static void ingresar()throws IOException{
                double precio, total;
                int nroDias, dni, numero;
                char tipo, estado;
                String correo, nombres, direccion;
        
                System.out.println("---Datos de Reserva---");
                System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del cliente: ");
                System.out.println("Nombres: ");
                nombres = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Dni: ");
                dni=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Direccion: ");
                direccion=br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Correo: ");
                correo=br.readLine();
                oHspd=new Huesped(nombres, direccion, dni, correo);
                nombres=huespedes.regitrarHuespedes(oHspd);
                System.out.println("Dias a quedarse: ");
                nroDias=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese tipo de Habitacion: ");
                tipo= br.readLine().charAt(0);
        
                
                if(tipo=='S'){
                 numero=1;
                 precio=300;
                 estado='O';
                 total=nroDias*precio;
                    System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                    System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                    oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                    numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                    oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                    nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                    System.out.println(oF.toString());
                    
                }
                if(tipo=='D'){
                 numero=1;
                 precio=400;
                 estado='O';
                 total=nroDias*precio;
                    System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                    System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                      oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                    numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                    oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                    nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                    System.out.println(oF.toString());
                }
                if(tipo=='M'){
                 numero=1;
                 precio=500;
                 estado='O';
                 total=nroDias*precio;
                    System.out.println("El tipo de habitación es: "+tipo);
                    System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
                      oH=new Habitacion(oHspd, numero, tipo, precio, estado);
                    numero=habitaciones.registrarHabitaciones(oH);
                    oF=new FichaHospedaje(oHspd, oH, nroDias);
                    nroDias=fichas.registrarFicha(oF);
                    System.out.println(oF.toString());
                }
            }
            static void listar()throws IOException{
                System.out.println("--Reporte--");
                System.out.println(huespedes.listarHuespedes());
            }
        }
```

Comment: yo no entiendo cual es tu problema... a que te referis con agregar una opcion mas al switch? a que switch?

Comment: "Por algún motivo no me lo permite" es una mala descripción del problema. Sale algún error? Qué error? Se detiene el programa? La opción que dices que no funciona en tu menú es la 1? Recuerda que no sabemos nada de tu problema más allá de lo que escribes, así que... escríbenos :)

Answer (score -1):

la respuesta es:

```
switch (true) {

 case (var1 === true && var2 === true) :
   //agrega tu codigo
   break;
 case (var1 === false && var2 === false) :
   //agrega tu codigo
   break;

  default:

}
```

Comment: Por supuesto que tiene un switch

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. El switch _existe_ pero el OP indica que no puede ingresar datos por motivos que aún desconocemos.